# How to Return an Array from a Nested ForEach Method?

Tags: javascript, foreach, nested

I have been working with a data structure for days and days, and am finally getting the data I want from it using a nested forEach loop. Trouble is, I'm getting a string for each loop, so in my console. I see a long list of individual strings for each item. I need to see an array of all of the strings.

Can anyone tell me how I can change my code to achieve this result? Or am I going about it the whole wrong way? Thanks.

```
  data.forEach(brandGuideline => {
    brandGuideline.children.forEach(child => {
      const brandGuidelineAlias = child.component.alias;
      console.log(brandGuidelineAlias); // Long list of individual strings. Can this be an array? 
    });
  });
```

I have tried creating an empty array and pushing my data into it, but that didn't work because I was inside of the forEach -- so I ended up getting a huge array for each of the items. Duh.

I have also tried wrapping my logic in a function and pushing the data into an array at the end, but that doesn't work because the array is out of scope. Blah.

Here is what I had tried earlier (in answer to Barmar):

```
let arrayOfAliases = [];
  data.forEach(brandGuideline => {
  brandGuideline.children.forEach(child => {
  const brandGuidelineAliases = child.component.alias;
  console.log(brandGuidelineAliases); // Need to only show buttons if 
  'brand-guidelines' is part of the path.
  arrayOfAliases.push(brandGuidelineAliases);
  console.log('Alias Array: ', arrayOfAliases);
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe look into the `.map()` function? It's not clear what you need to do, what your data looks like and what you want the result to be.

Comment: There is no return from a `forEach` it is always `undefined`

Comment: Pushing onto an array should have worked. Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a flat map approach for the outer array and a simple mapping for the inner array

```
result = data
    .flatMap(({ children }) => children.map(({ component: { alias } }) => alias));
```

Comment: no need for these destructurings,  a simple `data.flatMap(item => item.children.map(child => child.component.alias))` is shorter and way more readable.

Comment: See also my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use a flatMap.

```
data.flatMap(brandGuideline => 
    brandGuideline.children.map(child => child.component.alias))
```

This should give you an array containing all aliasses.

Comment: This reply is exactly as helpful as the one I marked 'correct.' To be fair, I marked the answer that arrived first. Thank you so much!